# What is the stance on unfamiliar English words?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/118060/6188) question used the word `prepone` which I had never heard of and initially thought was a typo.  I was going to edit it based on the context<sup>1</sup>, but on a hunch I googled the word and found that it is a perfectly cromulent Indian English antonym to `postpone`

So what is the consensus here?  Just because my vocabulary doesn't include `prepone`, does that give me reason to edit the question and replace it with a synonym that I *do* know?

---

1. Being that the OP wanted to enter Schengen area earlier than his Visa date.

Comment: Of related interest at EL&U: *[Is “prepone” being used outside India?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808)* and perhaps *[What is wrong in “Please don't pluck the flowers” and other phrases used in the Indian subcontinent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43597/)*, among others dealing with the particularly subcontinental uses of words and phrases like *kindly*, *doubt*, *good name*, *needful*, or *sheeter* to name a few.

Comment: Did you ever have any doubt about the meaning of *prepone?*

Comment: @phoog Of course I had doubts .. **I initially thought it was a typo**.  However last week I had just finished reading `The Prodigal Tongue: The Love-Hate Relationship Between American and British English` so that probably pushed me to google the word. (BTW Fascinating book)

Comment: @PeterM, I believe phoog was making a joke about the Indian use of "doubt" to mean "question".

Comment: I know *prepone* but not *cromulent*!

Answer (score 13):

My mantra is: if it makes the post clearer then edit it. Expressions and idioms that are geographically localised can be, by that same nature, not familiar to the rest of the people browsing the site so editing them often makes the post clearer.

Comment: While it may be unfamiliar to most, *prepone* is not likely to be unclear to many.

Comment: @phoog I disagree. *Prepone* is not a word an ESL/EFL speaker will encounter outside of the subcontinent. The back-formation is recognizable to a proficient user of English, especially one with some education, but it is needlessly burdensome to other ESL/EFL speakers.

Comment: @choster You can only unravel *prepone* once you understand what a *pone* is. I couldn't make the connection with *postpone* and I am a native speaker.

Comment: I agree, but be careful!  You might end up changing a reasonably obvious phrase (even if it is not idiomatic for most people) into something that is completely idiomatic to your version of English - and completely incomprehensible outside it.

Answer (score 2):

"Please don't pluck the flowers" has a pretty clear meaning, even if it's an Indian usage, but "prepone" doesn't have clear meaning to non-Indian speakers.  I think choosing phrasing that will be easy to understand for all speakers of English, no matter the dialect or their native tongue, is always advisable, so I'd be in favour of modifying the post accordingly.

Comment: I was going to edit out prepone, but decided not to because, in contrast to this answer, it is a word whose meaning is perfectly clear on first hearing, at least for anyone who knows the extremely common word *postpone* and that the prefixes *pre-* and *post-* are opposites.

Comment: @phoog One could always insert a synonym in square brackets as an edit, to improve readability.

Comment: The problem with that solution here (and, no doubt, one reason why *prepone* is a successful word) is that there is no single word that can replace it.  The only equivalent expressions I can think of are phrases, and many of them awkward at that.  Can you think of one?

Comment: @phoog Alas, the original question has been edited to remove the word, so I can't come with an alternative.  It's true that a phrase might be required.

Comment: You could always edit it back ;-)  The history is available by clicking the link that says "edited 2 days ago" above the name of the most recent editor.  But I didn't necessarily mean that to be a suggestion that we restore the title of this question.  I was just curious whether you'd thought of a synonym, since I haven't been able to.

Comment: To me (brought up with Australian English) not plucking the flowers makes perfect sense.  @Phoog I asked my wife (who works with words as a job) for an antonym to postpone and she couldn't come up with one either.

Answer (score 1):

For this site - and not the language sites - I suggest the conservative solution of immediately editing everything you don’t find in a larger dictionary. For the rest comment and seek agreement with the original poster. We all love the content we create.

We all access this site using a computer, pad or phone. I am very certain the overwhelming majority of these devices provide big dictionaries. Mine just needed to clicks to show *prepone*, but doesn’t show your *[cromulent](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent)*.

Comment: I agree with taking the more conservative approach, but for what it's worth, *cromulent* is [included in Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cromulent) and [featured in a Merriam-Webster blog post](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/internets-favorite-words), both widely respected as general purpose references, online and offline. The most useful EL&U coverage is probably *[How popular is the word “cromulent”? If I use this word in conversation with native speakers, doesn’t it look out of place?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/49251)*

Comment: @choster fine. Then use it. I don’t say my dictionary is the best. But given the recent origin it is certainly absent from a lot of good dictionaries.

Answer (score -4):

I would personally not replace the word (now you know it is a good word if not readily used where you live) but explain it in a few more words, in an edit.
(Or, if you are not happy to edit, in a comment.)

But that is my personal point of view and I am not sure how the site usually handles it.

Comment: I agree with this, especially since "explaining" the word is hardly necessary.

Answer (score -4):

I was going to edit the question on the assumption that a non-native English speaker had invented the word by analogy with *postpone,* but I never had any doubt about the meaning of the word.  Then I saw that it is in widespread use in India, and decided to leave it.

If the word were confusing to non-Indian readers (as with words like *lakh* and *crore),* I would say it should be changed.  But as it is, there's not much reason to remove it.  What else could it mean?

The [Wiktionary citations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Citations:prepone#English) leave me with the suspicion that it has been independently coined on several occasions.

In short, I think the standard ought to be intelligibility by a global English-speaking audience.

Comment: If I start from cornpone (also a perfectly reasonable word) as the analogy, I get a pretty different picture though... What might seem obvious in (any-kind-of) English can often be weird...

Comment: @JonCuster *compone* has in its favor the fact that it is an actual word in several languages, as well as the similarity to *component,* but the availability of *compose* probably works against it.

Comment: Note that kerning appears to have made you turn c-o-r-n into c-o-m. Not sure of the status of cornpone in other languages...